# theos tweak is not loaded into app when 3rd party framework is linked

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos

I'm using theos to link a 3rd framwork into my test tweak, which does nothing but a log, and it seems after linking the framework, the tweak.dylib is not loaded into app at all. If I comment out the framework in makefile, the tweak works well. Any idea? Thanks

The makefile is simple about the framework:

```
ARCHS = arm64

include $(THEOS)/makefiles/common.mk

ADDITIONAL_OBJCFLAGS = -fobjc-arc

TWEAK_NAME = WebServerTest
WebServerTest_FILES = Tweak.xm


WebServerTest_CFLAGS += -F./Frameworks
WebServerTest_LDFLAGS += -F./Frameworks -framework GCDWebServers

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk

after-install::
    install.exec "killall -9 SpringBoard"
```

The tweak.xm is very simple:

```
%ctor {
    NSLog(@"Staring up tweak...");
    %init();
}
```

So if I comment out above

> WebServerTest_CFLAGS += -F./Frameworks
>
> WebServerTest_LDFLAGS += -F./Frameworks -framework GCDWebServers

The tweak is working fine:

```
Aug 13 10:06:20 iOS-Dev SpringBoard(WebServerTest.dylib)[10378] <Notice>: Staring up tweak...
```

However if I start linking the framework, the WebServerTest.dylib is not loaded at all

I manually checked a test app in lldb cmd `image list`, it shows WebServerTest.dylib is not loaded at all

Any idea? Or how do I start to debug what's wrong? Because I'm not sure where is the possible cause.

env: iOS 12.0, unc0ver 3.1.0

> otool -l WebServerTest.dylib | fgrep -A5 LC_LOAD_DYLIB

shows

```
--
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 72
         name @rpath/GCDWebServers.framework/GCDWebServers (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 08:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
--
```

so it seems using the @rpath, I could understand, but can I embed the framework into the tweak.dylib, so it can be loaded automatically?

Comment: Sounds like a framework loading issue. Can you post the output of `otool -l WebServerTest.dylib | fgrep -A5 LC_LOAD_DYLIB`?

Comment: Yeah, it's probably the linker failing to find GCDWebServers framework. LC_LOAD_DYLIB command for GCDWebServers in WebServerTest.dylib will show which path the linker is looking at.

Comment: @Siguza old friend you are on stack overflow?! great. I have posted the otool output about the framework, it's using rpath. So in this case, how can I bundle the framework into the tweak dylib?

Comment: @creker posted in the question, thank you

Comment: so it seems using the @rpath, I could understand, but can I embed the framework into the tweak.dylib, so it can be loaded automatically? Please give answer so I can accept to give credits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever you're putting `GCDWebServers.framework` isn't where dyld is looking for it. There are a few ways to fix this.

You could either patch `GCDWebServers`'s `LC_ID_DYLIB` command to contain an absolute path - you'd probably want to see `man install_name_tool` for that.

Or you could add some `-rpath` flag to your `LDFLAGS`. Specifically, if your `GCDWebServers` was located in `/mypath/GCDWebServers.framework/GCDWebServers`, you'd add:

```
-rpath /mypath/
```

Or, if you wanna have `GCDWebServers.framework` just next to your dylib, no matter the absolute path, you should be able to use:

```
-rpath @loader_path/
```

For more information, see `man dyld` and `man ld`.

Comment: how can I let theos to embed the framework into the tweak dylib?

Comment: That's not gonna work in any reasonable fashion. A dylib is not a folder, and a compiled framework is not something you can statically link against anymore.

Comment: Ah I see. So if I can get the source code, either build a static library (xxx.a) to embed, correct?

Comment: ‭‮‬Y‭‮‬e‭‮‬s‭‮‬.‭‮‬

Comment: about your second way to add `-rpath @loader_path/`, is it in the tweak makefile like `WebServerTest_LDFLAGS += -rpath @loader_path/`? I added and compile, but the otool path is still ` @rpath/GCDWebServers.framework/GCDWebServers`

Comment: I'm a little confused who's LDFLAGS you are referring to

Comment: Confirmed `WebServerTest_LDFLAGS += -rpath @loader_path/` is working, after copying the framework into @loader_path/, the tweak loaded! looks like the failed loading will lead to tweak not load at all.